# saving big number of boolean values

Tags: c#, binary

I need to save **huge** number of boolean values (bits) in memory. If I using `List<bool>` after some time I get `OutOfMemoryException`, Is there any way to save big number of bits without splitting to chunks?

Comment: are you using database for your application? btw which type of application it is windows or web?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi I wrote that it should be **in memory**.

Comment: Are those bool values ordered/indexed in any way?

Comment: How big is **huge**? 2 million, 3 million?

Comment: @Grx70 yes, they should be ordered as I added them.

Comment: @MattTester lets say 250 million

Comment: Well then I can see no other way than storing 8 bool values in one byte-typed variable...

Comment: A 250 million generic list could be easily initialized on my 32 bit machine. Maybe more than 250,000,000?

Comment: @ssett I checked and the list should be more than 250 million, around 750 million.

Comment: You're wasting 7/8th of the memory just by using 8 bits / actual bit of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code your boolean variables. I give you an example:

assume 32 bool variables are in list: 1001001100101100000001011010010

If you want to save all these variables in memory without coding them, you should use at least 10 bytes, but by using a simple coding algorithm you can save significant amount of your memory. A simple suggestion algorithm for these 32 boolean variables is to save them as a 32bit int =**1234567890**. In this way memory usage will slake to 4 bytes only!

It is natural than coding of every data needs processing it, so CPU usage will be increase instead of memory usage.

Comment: Without usage of coding algorithm, your 250000000 variables needs 238MB memory that is too many. But after coding data, only 29MB memory need. And by using better coding algorithm this amount can be less than 1-2 MB.

Comment: I did this but I stack at the point of copying the integers into byte array. I have int list with increasing size: `int[] _list = new int[1000]`, how should I convert it to byte array?

Comment: I didn't understand your problem with this way, explain more plz.

Comment: Whenever you need every bool variable of your data, you should decode your coded data and extract your variable. In the above example assume after coding into an integer, you need 10th variable of your list, you just need to logical operations (e.g. logical and '&'). Got it? :)

Comment: Mind you that this is the way of storing an array of bools rather than a list of bools, because it'd not be easy to remove a value at an arbitrary index...

Comment: "It'd not be easy to remove a value at an arbitrary index", but it's possible, isn't it? :)

Comment: One integer is not enough to store the data I need so I created array of integers, after I filled in all the data I should convert it to byte array, I did so: `Buffer.BlockCopy(_list, 0, array, 0, array.Length);` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Though array of integers is not a good idea, but why it doesn't work? What is the problem?

Comment: If it works enjoy it:) Integer array is not good idea because integer is integer! It's better using a data structure be designed for bits. As @Denis Itskovich mentioned using of BitArray maybe help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `List<bool>`, however, if you're trying to use very large lists in 64 bit environments you need to enable large objects in the application configuration.

Get more info from : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054.aspx)

Comment: But boolean list cost to much and it's not good to me because the program should run on 32bit environments also.

Comment: Looking at the docs, the maximum array length would still 4,294,967,295 - it's just total memory size can be bigger.

Comment: @MattTester For some reason at 134,217,729's item I getting `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: @ZilbermanRafael In this way, I think you should encode your raw data if you really don't want to splitting them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, which provides a compact way to store bit masks

Comment: I need it to be dynamic, I don't know exactly how much bits I should save.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply reserving the space up-front? that way the list doesn't have to worry about growth for a good long while. You've hypothetically stated in your comment that it should be able to store 250 million. But the following runs just fine at least for me and should potentially allow you to store more since it's not having to constantly resize:

```
List<bool> test = new List<bool>(1000000000);
```

That being said, you would take up much less memory to store this at the bit level. That solution would probably be preferable but you'll have to write quite a bit more custom code for this.

Also...it seems like a really strange request. Perhaps there's a different way to approach your problem?

Comment: Tried this, still got `OutOfMemoryException`. If you asking what I am trying to do, I am tying to encode string using huffman coding.

Comment: Can you stream the results to a file?